# Getting email aliases via API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to link an email with its aliases.

For instance the same email `xyz@example.com` might have alias `123@example.com`.

I would like to use the microsoft graph API or some office 365 based API to get the list of aliases to an email.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The e-mail aliases are in the `proxyAddresses` property of the user object in the Graph API.

Read the [intro](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet), which also has links to samples to get you started

Comment: seems like this works only for business accounts(office365) and not personal accounts(outlook), would you know if there are other workarounds to get the same for personal accounts?

Comment: I don't off the top of my head. You should post a new question, that will give it more visibility.

Comment: It appears that the `proxyAddresses` property is not available by default, so you need to specify that you need it like this: `/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,proxyAddresses`